# PHP ignore_user_abort is Not working on IIS 10

Tags: php, ajax, apache, iis, fastcgi

I want to complete PHP request even if the Ajax session is closed from user side. I manage to do it on Apache by adding `ignore_user_abort(True)` to my php file but it is not working on IIS 10 with FASTCGI. tried to google any solution with no luck. I'm using PHP v7.4 and IIS v10 on windows server 2019.

below is just a test code to open a file and print the connection status. it is working perfect on Apache but on IIS, it stops writing ponce session is closed.

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort ( TRUE );
echo "hello\n";

$x=0;
$log_filename = ".\\test.txt";
while (@ ob_end_flush());
while ($x<100)
{
  echo($x ."\n");
  $status = connection_aborted();
  file_put_contents($log_filename, $x ." - " .$status ."\n", FILE_APPEND);
  $x++;
  @ flush();
  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Comment: This seems to be an old bug (since 2011): https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60586#1378935714. It's still marked as open though.

Comment: @Magnus I saw that Bug but that was for V5.3, I'm using V7.4

Comment: Yes, but the issue can still be the same. The last comment with the same issue was from 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `fastcgi_finish_request()` This function flushes all response data to the client and finishes the request. This allows for time-consuming tasks to be performed without leaving the connection to the client open.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to close the connection as I return data while running. The main goal here is to return live data to the user and if he close the tab or browser, the script keep running till the end.